# Custom SharePoint SPUserField does not show up in InfoPath in Browser

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, peoplepicker

I have create a custom field that inherits from SPFieldUser.  Everything works fine on the site and the value displays fine in InfoPath as long as I am either in preview mode or select Edit In InfoPath.  As soon as I view the form in the browser the field's value no longer displays.  Has anyone seen anything like this before?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but that kinda makes sense to me, If editing a publishing page in SharePoint, the owner field for example is metadata on the page and can be filled in edit mode but when in display mode this metadata is not shown unless I explicitly show it. The fields shown in edit mode and display mode are different for pages and I am assuming the same for InfoPath forms.